# How to distiguish if SSL certificate is for both domain and subdomains or for domain only?

Tags: tls, certificates

Provider suggests me two types of SSL certificates: for domain only or for domain and subdomains. First one is cheaper.

Currently I already have certificate for previous year. How to know, if it was bought for domain only or for domain and subdomains?

Comment: You want to know if it is a "wildcard certificate"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate

Comment: You need to first show us the details of your certificate (via tools like OpenSSL, ["Checking Using OpenSSL"](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html)).

Answer (score 1):

When you purchase certificate for single domain, Subject Alternative Names (SAN) extension will typically include two entries:

```
example.com
www.example.com
```

this will allow:

- parent domain
- `www` host under parent domain

when you purchase certificate for arbitrary subdomains (without hosts in subdomains), then you can get a wildcard certificate with the following entries:

```
example.com
*.example.com
```

this will allow:

- parent domain
- any subdomain without hosts (e.g. `www.sub.example.com` is not covered)
- any host under parent domain

if you want to have hosts under subdomains, then all subdomains must be listed explicitly, e.g.

```
example.com
*.example.com
*.sub1.example.com
*.sub2.example.com
```

this combination will allow:

- parent domain
- any subdomain
- any host under parent domain
- any host under `sub1.example.com` domain
- any host under `sub2.example.com` domain

Answer (score 1):

Use your browser (or other TLS client) to view the certificate after connecting, or just look at the certificate file with a tool that will parse it for you (such as the certificate viewer built into Windows). Look in particular for the "Common Name" and "Subject Alternate Names" (SAN) fields, which will list the domain name(s) for which the certificate is valid. If either one starts with `*.` - as in, `*.yourdomain.com` - that indicates that subdomains are supported (typically such certificates will also list the root domain, `yourdomain.com`, as one of the entries in one of those fields). The `*` is called a "wildcard", and a cert that uses one in the CN/SAN fields is called a "wildcard certificate". Wildcard certs are sometimes more expensive.

Note that a cert can cover many domains (and/or subdomains of one or more particular domains) explicitly, without using a wildcard. Certs that cover multiple domains are often more expensive, since it's essentially multiple certs in one.

---

I'd be remiss to not mention: you can get a cert issued without paying anybody at all. LetsEncrypt is a well-known free certificate authority, trusted by all major browsers, and they will not only issue as many certs as you need for free, they provide tools to automate the renewal of these certs (their expiration is short, but automatic renewing is easy on most platforms).